# Why is the square root transformation recommended for count data?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, data-transformation, poisson-distribution, count-data, variance-stabilizing

It is often recommended to take the square root when you have count data.  (For some examples on CV, see @HarveyMotulsky's answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11359/what-could-be-the-reason-for-using-square-root-transformation-on-data/11366#11366), or @whuber's answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46334/line-graph-has-too-many-lines-is-there-a-better-solution/46350#46350).)  On the other hand, when fitting a generalized linear model with a response variable distributed as Poisson, the log is [the canonical link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression).  This is sort of like taking a log transformation of your response data (although more accurately it is taking a log transformation of $\lambda$, the parameter that governs the response distribution).  Thus, there is some tension between these two.

- **How do you reconcile this (apparent) discrepancy?**
- **Why would the square root be better than the logarithm?**

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The square root is [approximately variance-stabilizing for the Poisson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-stabilizing_transformation). There are a number of variations on the square root that improve the properties, such as [adding $\frac{3}{8}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe_transform) before taking the square root, or the [Freeman-Tukey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe_transform#Alternatives) ($\sqrt{X}+\sqrt{X+1}$ - though it's often adjusted for the mean as well).

In the plots below, we have a Poisson $Y$ vs a predictor $x$ (with mean of $Y$ a multiple of $x$), and then $\sqrt{Y}$ vs $\sqrt{x}$ and then $\sqrt{Y+\frac{3}{8}}$ vs $\sqrt{x}$.

[image]

The square root transformation somewhat improves symmetry - though not as well as the $\frac{2}{3}$ power does [1]:

[image]

If you particularly want near-normality (as long as the parameter of the Poisson is not really small) and don't care about/[can adjust for](http://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/insight/chap39/sect57.htm) heteroscedasticity, try $\frac{2}{3}$ power.

The canonical link is not generally a particularly good transformation for Poisson *data*; log zero being a particular issue (another is heteroskedasticity; you can also get left-skewness even when you don't have 0's). If the smallest values are not too close to 0 it can be useful for linearizing the mean. It's a good 'transformation' for the conditional population *mean* of a Poisson in a number of contexts, but not always of Poisson data. However if you do want to transform, one common strategy is to add a constant $y^*=\log(y+c)$ which avoids the $0$ issue. In that case we should consider what constant to add. Without getting too far from the question at hand, values of $c$ between $0.4$ and $0.5$ work very well (e.g. in relation to bias in the slope estimate) across a range of $\mu$ values. I usually just use $\frac12$ since it's simple, with values around $0.43$ often doing just slightly better.

As for why people choose one transformation over another (or none) -- that's really a matter of what they're doing it to achieve.

[1]: Plots patterned after Henrik Bengtsson's plots in his handout "Generalized Linear Models and Transformed
Residuals" [see here](http://www1.maths.lth.se/bioinformatics/calendar/20040305/BengtssonH_20040305-GeneralizedLinearModelsAndTransformedResiduals.handouts.pdf)
(see first slide on p4). I added a little y-jitter and omitted the lines.

Comment: +1, thanks for your help. I gather the square root (or slight variations) is best for normalizing & stabilizing the variance of the Poisson, whereas the log is best for linearizing the mean. Your point about the problem w/ $\log 0$ is also a good one. Nonetheless, I find it counter-intuitive that the best transformation differs between these two contexts.

Comment: OK, I've been thinking about what you've put here, & here's my synthesis: The optimal transformations differ in these 2 situations b/c what you're trying to achieve differs. The sqrt is better for stabilizing the variance & normalizing the distribution. The log maps the interval $(0, +\infty)$ to $(-\infty, +\infty)$ which allows the transformation of the mean, $\lambda$, to be linear in model parameters. The sqrt does not have this property. W/ a GLiM, it doesn't matter that the variance isn't constant, b/c the response distribution is set as Poisson. Is that about right?

Comment: What will be linear in the parameters *depends on the model*. It's perfectly possible for that linearity to be on the original scale or the square root scale or some other scale. Even the - useful/important - 'maps to the real line' property isn't unique to the log function. The reason the log link is 'natural' is because of the way it simplifies the GLM by having a sufficient statistic of $X'y$.

Comment: +1 The square root is merely a starting point for dealing with count data. The logarithm also is a good choice. The data will often tell you which one is more successful in obtaining a useful and succinct description.  Gung, in the [answer you refer to](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46350), the demonstration that the square root was a good choice lies in the symmetric distribution of the non-outlying residuals apparent in the right hand figure. When you vary the parameters of the simulation, you will find that symmetry is maintained.

Comment: @whuber When you say the logarithm is a good choice -- it would seem to have a problem with $\log(0)$. That requires either doing something other than $\log(X)$ (such as actually using a shifted-log) or restricting it to cases with no zeros. The first makes the good choice actually a different choice and the second seems to diminish its value rather significantly.

Comment: @Glen I did not say logs are *always* a good choice. But sometimes they are superior to roots. When zero counts appear then yes, you need a ["started" logarithm](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6150/is-visualization-sufficient-rationale-for-transforming-data/6177#6177). Other threads here have [discussed ways to obtain a starting value](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41361/choosing-c-such-that-logx-c-would-remove-skew-from-the-population/41377#41377). When there are no zero counts in the data, then there will be no problems with logs at all.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth annotating this thread with an indication that there can be limitations to transformations of count data, esp. if there are 0s that require a log(x+1).  A good ref is Bolker(2012) Generalized linear models for disease ecologists, and citations therein.

Comment: Hi guys, hi @whuber! Why would you transform the count data themselves? All these approaches seem a bit "dirty" - i.e. why $\sqrt{x+1}$ and not $\sqrt{x+2}$, the same for $\log{x+1}$ etc. I think the best and cleanest is the GLM approach when you **log-transform the expected value**, not the count itself! So no problem with $\text{log}(0)$. This approach is not only useful for the response variable, **[it can even be used in the predictor!](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/61756/5509)**.

Comment: @Tomas As for why Freeman-Tukey or $\sqrt{x+3/8}$ rather than  $\sqrt{x}$ or $\sqrt{x+c}$ for some other $c$, there are good reasons for both Freeman-Tukey and $\sqrt{x+3/8}$  (for example, to do with making skewness closer to 0), but if you want to get into those in detail, that would be a whole new question.

Comment: @glen_b  my comment above suggest exactly the opposite direction than arguing which constant is the best..

Comment: @Tomas That was in response to "why $\sqrt{x+1}$ and not $\sqrt{x+2}$"; the implication of your comment does have some response - the numbers aren't just arbitrary.

Comment: If $X$ is Poisson($\lambda$) then $Y = \sqrt{X+ 1/4}$ has approximately mean $\sqrt{\lambda}$ and variance 1/4. Moreover, for large $\lambda$, $Y$ will be Gaussian.

Comment: @utobi Yes, the $\frac14$ option should be mentioned, thanks. The approximate variance term applies for adding 0, 3/8, 1/4 or any small fraction, as does the asymptotic Gaussianity. Brown, Zhang and Zhao (2001) encourage the use of $\frac14$ because of the improved accuracy of the mean; in [Brown and Zhao](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~lzhao/papers/MyPublication/Newtest_Sankhya_2002.pdf) (2002) they prefer $\frac38$ because of the more stable variance. Which is better depends on the application.