# Capturing variability using ANOVA on date

Tags: anova, categorical-data, count-data, poisson-regression, overdispersion

I have a dataset of traffic count at several intersections at various dates. Most of the intersections were counted only once. I want to know if there is a significant daily and monthly variability in peak hour volumes.

So I ran an ANOVA model in R that look like this:

```
fit<-lm(trafficcount~factor(year)+factor(month))+factor(day)+factor(month))*factor(day))

anova(fit)
```

Looking at p-values, I then conclude whether or not there is a significant variability among day or month or year.
Is that an acceptable method to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Your count variable `trafficcount` maybe Poisson distributed, so you could change your linear model for a poisson GLM (generalized linear model),  or use the linear model with a square root transformed response variable $\sqrt{\text{trafficcount}}$.  The square root transform is the variance stabilizing transform for the Poisson family,  see [Why is the square root transformation recommended for count data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46418/why-is-the-square-root-transformation-recommended-for-count-data).  But the Poisson GLM approach is probably better.

```
In R the poisson regression would look like:

fit <- glm(trafficcount ~ factor(year) + factor(month) + factor(day) +          factor(month) * factor(day), family=poisson(link=log))

anova(fit)
```

To your additional question in the comment:  If the time interval for counting is not constant for the sites, you can include the exposure time in the model as an **offset**:  In R your formula would include `~ offset(log(exposure_time)) + factor(year) + ...`.   Then the Poisson approach should be OK.  But, you must be on alert for **overdispersion**, in R you can check for that using the `quasipoisson` family function.

Comment: Thanks! I should add that the time interval is not constant between to two sites. I do not think I can apply a Poisson distribution here, can I?

Comment: You can use a poisson (an alternative might be negative binomial). The difference in time interval (exposure) is taken care of the the offset.

Comment: If you think @kjetilbhalvorsen's answer cleared your impending confusion(s), please upvote it and [accept](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the same.