# Strange variance weights for Poisson GLM for square root link

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, link-function, irls

Is there a reason why all the variance weights from a Poisson GLM are equal when a square root link is used? That is (on R):

```
glm(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4, family=poisson(link=sqrt), data=df)$weights
```

Always returns equal weights for all observations when a square root link is used; but different weights when the canonical (log) link is used. Does anyone know why?

Comment: The square root is the variance stabilizing transformation for the poisson distribution

Comment: Seet [Why is the square root transformation recommended for count data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46418/why-is-the-square-root-transformation-recommended-for-count-data)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The weights in the `glm` function are

$$
w_i = \left.\frac{(\partial \mu_i/\partial\eta_i)^2}{\text{var}(\mu_i)}\right|_{\mu_i=h(\eta_i) = \eta_i^2}
$$

So if $\mu_i = \eta_i^2$ and you recall that $\text{var}(\mu_i)=\mu_i$ then $\partial \mu_i/\partial\eta_i = 2\eta_i$ so $w_i = 4$. This is what you get from `glm`

```
> counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
> outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
> treatment <- gl(3,3)
> glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson(link = "sqrt"))
> 
> glm.D93$weights
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

On the other hand, the log-link function has $\partial \mu_i/\partial\eta_i =  \exp(\eta_i)$ and thus you get different weights.

Comment: +1, excellent answer, clear, to the point, well formatted, etc.